# How do I get my Sound indicator back

Tags: sound, xubuntu, indicator, pulseaudio

I run Xubuntu 13.10 on a Lenovo S10 Ideapad Netbook. I have 200GB HDD Space and 1GB of ram. I wanted to give ubuntu a second chance but I installed it using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop` I was able to purge it via A website to get back to a pure Xubuntu. When I rebooted my volume shortcut on my keyboard didn't work so I re-installed Pulse Audio. Now I logged on this morning and my sound indicator is missing. Can I get it back?

Comment: You can.  Just right click on the Panel --> Panel --> Add New Item.

Comment: I have tried this and all I get is the Wifi indicator again.

Comment: @Mightyno92, "I was able to purge it via A website". Could you point out (put a link..) to the procedure used to purge `ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: [Get back to a pure Xubuntu](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/tag/pure-xubuntu/)

Comment: Have you tried adding `xfce4-mixer` to the panel?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install volumeicon-alsa
nohup volumeicon-alsa &
```

you can then add the command `volumeicon-alsa` to your Settings > Start-up Applications

to fix keyboard bindings, Settings > Keyboard > shortcuts > new. Click on the new binding and it will autocapture your key combo when you press the volume controls on your keyboard.

For the volume increase key combo bind the command: `amixer set 'Master' 5%+`

For the volume decrease key combo bind the command: `amixer set 'Master' 5%-`

You can change `5%` to whatever you want, I find 3-5 is generally a good number

Comment: That didn't work at all.

Comment: Well what happened?

Comment: I installed what you said and the indicator didn't show up.

Comment: run: `volumeicon-alsa`. Does it show up now?

Comment: how do I get it to run?

Comment: keyboard shortcut Alt-F2, then volumeicon-alsa

Comment: it comes up with a red exclamation mark.